# Distribution of infection time $T \mid T < \infty$ with exponential waiting times

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, mathematical-modeling

I want to solve the following exercise in "Statistical Models" by Davison:

> A family has two children A and B. Child A catches an infectious
> disease D which is so rare that the probability that B catches it
> other than from A can be ignored. Child A is infectious for a time $U$
> having probability density function $\alpha \exp(-\alpha u)$ , $u \geq 0$, and in any small
> interval of time $[t, t + δt]$ in $[0, U)$, B will catch D from A with
> probability $βδt + o(δt)$, where $α, β > 0$. Calculate the probability $ρ$
> that B does catch D. Show that, in a family where B is actually
> infected, the density function of the time to infection is $γ\exp(-γt)$ , $t\geq 0$, where $γ = α + β$.

For simplicity we can ignore $o(δt)$. If we let $T$ denote the infection time of B, then $\rho=P(T < \infty) = P(T \leq U)$ and conditioning version of law of total probability, I have computed that $\rho=\beta/(\alpha+\beta)$. To arrive at this I have further assumed to infection in disjoint intervals are independent.

I pressume that the random variable to be considered in the second part of the question is $T \mid T < \infty$ and hence using $\rho$ from before we just need to compute the marginal probability $P(T \leq t)$. But I cannot see how this becomes $\rho$ times the CDF of an Exp($\alpha + \beta$). Also I have been toying with the idea of viewing the probability of the minimum of two independent exponential distributions but I cannot convince myself of which events one wants to consider. One of these must surely be $U$. But conditioned on $T < \infty$, is it not true that $T \sim T \wedge U$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T \in [0, U] \cup \{\infty\}$ denotes the infection time of $B$, we have$$\mathrm P(T \in [t, t + \delta t] \mid \min(U, T) \ge t) = \beta \delta t + o(\delta t),$$
and likewise $$\mathrm P(\min(U, T) \in [t, t+\delta t] \mid \min(U, T) \ge t) = (\alpha + \beta)\delta t + o(\delta t).$$

We deduce that $\min(U, T) \sim \mathrm{Exp}(\alpha + \beta)$, so
$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm P(T \in [t, t + \delta t]) &= \mathrm P(\min(U, T) \ge t)\ \mathrm P(T \in [t, t + \delta t] \mid \min(U, T) \ge t)\\
&=\exp(-(\alpha+\beta) t)\ (\beta \delta t + o(\delta t))\\
&=\frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta}(\alpha + \beta)\exp(-(\alpha + \beta)t)\delta t + o(\delta t).\end{align*}$$
We can then conclude that $\mathrm P(T < \infty) = \beta / (\alpha + \beta)$, and $T \mid T < \infty \sim \mathrm{Exp}(\alpha + \beta).$

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on two points: 1)  How do you compute the probability of $\min(U,T)$? Do you use independence? And 2) how do you relate the distribution of this to $T \mid T < \infty$?

Comment: I'm not sure which part you want more information on, could you say more? @DK2412

Comment: 1) How do you arrive at $\mathrm P(\min(U, T) \in [t, t+\delta t] \mid \min(U, T) \ge t) = (\alpha + \beta)\delta t + o(\delta t).$? It is not clear to me how to compute this probability without implicitly assuming that $U$ and $T$ are independent. In general the minimum of two exponential are *not* again exponential.
2) How do you conclude $T \mid T < \infty \sim \text{Exp}(\alpha+\beta)$ from having computed $P(T \in [t,t\delta t])$? Do you divide by $P(T < \infty)$? Or use the continuous version of law of total probability? I hope it's clearer now :)

Comment: 1) I'm assuming that the system is a continuous-time Markov chain, which I don't think is explicitly stated, but is sort of implied with these kinds of questions. I agree it's not posed very well! 2) I recognise that the density of $T$ on $[0, \infty)$ has the form $pf(t)$, where $p \in [0, 1]$, and $f$ is the density of an $\mathrm {Exp}(\alpha + \beta)$ RV. So $p$ is the probability that $T < \infty$, and $f$ is its density given that event. @DK2412

Answer (score 0):

The result shows that the conditional distribution of the time to infection given that B is infected is an exponential distribution with parameter $\gamma = \alpha + \beta$. This means that the probability that B is infected within a time $t$ is given by:

$$P(T \leq t | T < \infty) = 1 - e^{-\gamma t}$$

where $T$ is the time to infection of B.

Therefore, the probability that B is infected given that A is infectious is given by:

$$\rho = P(T < \infty) = \frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta}$$

The result above shows that the conditional distribution of the time to infection given that B is infected is an exponential distribution with parameter $\gamma = \alpha + \beta$. This means that the probability that B is infected within a time $t$ is given by:

$$P(T \leq t | T < \infty) = 1 - e^{-\gamma t}$$

where $T$ is the time to infection of B.

Therefore, the probability that B is infected given that A is infectious is given by:

$$\rho = P(T < \infty) = \frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta}$$

Note that we have used the $\leq$ symbol instead of the $<$ symbol in the first equation because we are conditioning on the event that B is infected, which means that $T$ is finite.